# Swift / Spring - Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift

My 2nd question on here and it's Spring related yet again, your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is the line of code that receives the issue code:

```
var soundID : SystemSoundID = Internal.cache[url] ?? 0
```

and

```
Internal.cache[url] = soundID
```

Issue Code:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
```

Additional Code:

```
struct SoundPlayer {

static var filename : String?
static var enabled : Bool = true

private struct Internal {
    static var cache = [NSURL:SystemSoundID]()
}

static func playSound(soundFile: String) {

    if !enabled {
        return
    }

    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundFile, withExtension: nil) {

        var soundID : SystemSoundID = Internal.cache[url] ?? 0

        if soundID == 0 {
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url as CFURL, &soundID)
            Internal.cache[url] = soundID
        }

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)

    } else {
        print("Could not find sound file name `\(soundFile)`")
    }
}

static func play(file: String) {
    self.playSound(soundFile: file)
}
```

}

Comment: The [spring] tag is for questions about the Java http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/ framework. Is that really what you are talking about?

Comment: With the information from your previous question you might be able to fix that issue yourself. *Hint:* What type has the `url` variable?

Comment: No, my apologies, I meant the Spring iOS Animation Library for Swift.

Comment: @MartinR I have to ask your asistance again. After re-reading your answer on the previous question, I was sure it would be NSURL, but now i get an issue code: "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSURL'"

Just to note, this is my 3rd week learning Swift and coding on the whole, hence the reason for my noob level questions.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache directory is defined as

```
static var cache = [NSURL: SystemSoundID]()
```

i.e. the key is of the type `NSURL`. But `Bundle.main.url(...)` returns
a `URL`, which is the "corresponding" value type. You can either
bridge from `URL` to `NSURL`:

```
 var soundID = Internal.cache[url as NSURL] ?? 0
```

or (and that appears to me as the better solution), change the
dictionary definition to

```
static var cache = [URL: SystemSoundID]()
```

Comment: Well that was simple enough. The answer was a few lines above.
Thank you for taking the time to break it down. I understand the reason behind the change now.